# How to make byte array of string type data using c#

Tags: c#, arrays, database, byte

I have

```
string FieldName = "70778203048000022800101980197011000403364161025115108169019130064124025314701282420179220012222500653502306514513063501621600641710539012820602201612822031760654616264064251063248011208023217501282310240641420165320128137014031064148178170645902192050642120103250065217247064761631012941184144064122030190";
```

and I am trying to get it in byte array using this code

```
byte[] fingerbuffer1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FieldName); 
                     OR
byte[] fingerbuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FieldName);
```

but it gives encoded data of "FieldName" like

```
byte[] fingerbuffer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
```

but I need exact data of "FieldName" in byte[]

```
byte[] fingerbuffer = "70778203048000022800101980197011000403364161025115108169019130064124025314701282420179220012222500653502306514513063501621600641710539012820602201612822031760654616264064251063248011208023217501282310240641420165320128137014031064148178170645902192050642120103250065217247064761631012941184144064122030190";
```

**OR my second question is :- how same data can retrieve from database in byte[].**

Comment: What do you mean by "encoded data"? Show an example of what you expect the output to be vs what you are actually getting.

Comment: You will need to provide some more info, as it is not clear what you're requirement is. You have answered you're own question, "How to make byte array of string type data" - you're code does exactly this!

Comment: The values you are getting *are* the bytes, as they correspond to the ASCII values of the characters in your string -- `7` is `0x55`, `0` is `0x48`, `8` is `0x56`, so that first part of `70778` turns into the bytes `(0x)5548555556`. You seem to either be misunderstanding what a byte array is, or wanting something other than a byte array...

Answer (score -2):

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
     byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
     System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     return bytes;
}

static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
{
     char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
     System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
     return new string(chars);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your Answer but it also shows encoded string value